# CSS background-image relative background-color fixed z-index

Tags: css, background-image, z-index, background-color

my problem is:

I got this HTML:

```
<div id="UNDER">
</div>

<div id="OVER">
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
#UNDER
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: #004;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 50;
}

#OVER
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url("images/bg.jpg") center center no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9000;
}
```

But the background-image is behind **UNDER** and not over.

I try with the same code, just with background-color instead of background and it's working !

```
#UNDER
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: #004;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 50;
}

#OVER
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #009;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9000;
}
```

Any clue about to make it works with an image in background ?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to have `background` instead of `background-image`.

http://jsfiddle.net/e56Sp/

```
background: url("images/bg.jpg") center center no-repeat fixed;
```

Comment: Yeah sure ! I forgot to change it when I regrouped background-image, background-attachment, background-position and background-repeat, to have less lines. Sorry. (I edited my post to be clear ;) )

Comment: @user2961537 So does that mean it's fixed or still broken? I couldn't tell from your response. If still broken can you post a fiddle demonstrating that?

Comment: It's all right thanks (sorry to answer so late).
I think the problem was `background` instead of `background-image` but don't really know because I changed it too much time: `background` to `background-image`, `background-attachment`, `background-position` and `background-repeat`.